# Read line from a file

Tags: shell-script

Hello how can i read each line from a file and compare it with other file...
Actually that file should be taken from command line....
please help me out

```
if [[-f $@ ]];
    then
    for "$line" in $@;
    do
        if grep "^$line" /etc/passwd > /dev/null;
            then IFS=":";
            read usr pwd uid gid gcos home shell < <(grep "^$user" /etc/passwd);
            IFS=",";
            read name <<< "$gcos";
            printf "UID:%-10s Name:%s\n" "$uid" "$name";
        else
            echo "No User"
        fi
    done
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

> Hello how can i read each line from a file and compare it with other file.

If you are only trying to get a comparison between the two files, may I suggest:

#### Option #1 [sdiff](http://linux.die.net/man/1/sdiff) => side-by-side merge of file differences

```
sdiff file1 file2
```

Example Output:

```
abcdev                                                          abcdev
abcdev                                                          abcdev
abcdev                                                          abcdev
abcdev                                                        | abcde33
```

#### Option #2 [diff](http://linux.die.net/man/1/diff) => compare files line by line

```
diff file1 file2
```

Example Output:

```
4c4
< abcdev
---
> abcde33
```

#### Option #3 [vimdiff](http://linux.die.net/man/1/vimdiff) => edit two, three or four versions of a file with Vim and show differences

```
vimdiff file1 file2
```

Example screen (you can edit the files while in still seeing diff):

[image]

#### Option #4 [grep](http://linux.die.net/man/1/grep) => print lines matching a pattern

```
grep -Fxvf file1 file2
```

#### Flag Breakdown:

```
-F, --fixed-strings
  Interpret PATTERN as a list of fixed strings, separated by newlines, any of which is to be matched.    
-x, --line-regexp
  Select only those matches that exactly match the whole line.
-v, --invert-match
  Invert the sense of matching, to select non-matching lines.
-f FILE, --file=FILE
  Obtain patterns from FILE, one per line.  The empty file contains zero patterns, and therefore matches nothing.
```

Example Output:

```
abcde33
```